# Oracleデータベースの作成にDBCAで生成されたスクリプトを利用する利点は？

Tags: oracle

DBCAを使用してデータベースを作成する際に、スクリプトを生成して作成するほうが効率的なのでしょうか。スクリプトは、GUIで設定してきた値がとりあえず記載されていて、データベースを再作成する際にも便利と聴きましたが、熟練されたOracleエンジニアの方々はどうされていますか？

試しにスクリプトを生成してみたところ、結局ファイルシステム内の指定場所にはデータベースファイルができてしまうわけで、あまり意味を感じられませんでした。

また加えて、CREATE DATABASE文となったスクリプトが生成されると聴きましたが、そのようなものは見当たりませんでした。DBCAによって生成することのできるスクリプトはそれなりの使い方、使用価値があるものだとは思いますが、CREATE DATABASE文となったスクリプトは作れませんよね？

Answer (score 1):

Oracle はそこまで詳しくないので、あくまで一般的なスクリプトに対しての話になります。

例えば、以前と同じ設定でデータベースを作成しようとした場合、GUI だと手順書などを見比べながらになるかと思いますが、どうしても手違いが発生しがちです。

一方、スクリプトを用いた方法だと手順はすべてファイルに記述されているので、事前の準備さえ出来ていれば誰がいつ実行しても基本的には結果が同じものになります。

また、スクリプト (=CUI) でのインストールなら GUI が使えない環境でも作業ができるという利点があります。